# Replacing the appendLine in string builder in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder that builds a string. After it is all processed, it saves to a SQL Server table to be used as a csv.  How do I replace a part of the string including the newline?

The code is:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

temp.AppendLine("\"Text 1 \"");
temp.AppendLine("");
temp.AppendLine("\"My Text \"");
temp.AppendLine("");
temp.AppendLine("\"Text 2 \"");
temp.AppendLine("");
```

I want to replace the middle part but I can't get it correct because of the newlines/carriage returns.

```
temp = temp.Replace("\"My Text \"   ");
```

How do I grab the newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace new line charcater, use '\n' (a special charcater) :

- `temp = temp.Replace("\n","YOUR_REPLACING_STRING");`

Or use `Environment.NewLine`:

- `temp = temp.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"YOUR_REPLACING_STRING");`

If you want to **not** append a new line character in your string builder :

- Instead of `AppendLine()`, use `Append()` to not insert a new line character.

Comment: its actually \r\n is what I was looking for

Comment: If you're going to copy my suggestions, you could at least try and do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to not use `AppendLine()`. If you don't want new lines, use `Append()` instead.

But you can replace the new line with:

```
temp = temp.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```